# How to allocate an array of inner class in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I want to create an array of inner class objects, which don't have type parameter, but the containing class does has type parameter. Here is my scenario:

```
public class DFS<T> {
    
    private class Node {
        T data;
        // ...
    }

    public boolean find2Stack(Node N0) {
        // ...
        for (Node Z : deeper(N)) {
            if (!isVisited(Z))
                S.push(Z);
        }
    }
    // and more version of DFS implementations

    // ...

    // helper functions

    private Node[] deeper(Node n) {
        // TODO: ...                   
        return new Node[0]; // ERROR.
    }

}
```

I'm learning DFS algorithm. I just want to turn the pseudo-code into Java and don't want to implement the details of it today. So I want to create an length-`0`-array of `Node`, how can I do this?

I've searched some similar questions but I don't find an answer in my case: The inner class `Node` has no type parameter(I considered this none-generic, but I'm not sure) and I want to create an array of `Node`...

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Did you try `Node[] array = new Node[0];`?

Comment: @KevinAnderson: I did, I got error, let me upload a pic if you want to confirm.

Comment: By "DFS" do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search? Define your terms when posting on Stack Overflow if you want better Answers.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Yes, I meant Depth First Search, thanks for your clarification requirement.

Comment: @KevinAnderson: I hovered the mouse to underlined code to let the error shown by IDE(Integrated Development Env. I meant).

Comment: This might help: [How to create a generic array in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/529085)

Comment: @Tom: Do you mean that my inner-class `Node` is generic? Just want to clarify this, I thought that was not about my problem... In the problem `E` is a type parameter and he wanted to create `E[]` but is that the same as my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Node` is a non-static inner class of the generic outer class `DFS<T>`. That means it is within the scope of the generic parameter `T`. So when you write the unqualified name `Node`, it implicitly means `DFS<T>.Node`, which is a parameterized type, and Java disallows creation of an array of a parameterized type (just like how you cannot do `new List<String>[5]`).

Usually, one solution to not being able to create an array of a parameterized type is to create an array of the raw type instead. However, in this case, what is the raw type? It is not `Node`, as we have seen. Rather, you have to explicitly qualify it with the raw outer class: `DFS.Node`. So this works:

```
Node[] result = new DFS.Node[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

OK I found a way to make it compiled:

```
//...
return (Node[]) new Object[0];
```